# D3.select(this) but filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am working on an D3 forced graph and got a challenge. I added a "mouseenter" function which increase the radius of nodes if getting hovered.

```
.on("mouseenter", function(d) {
                    d3.select(this)
                        .transition()
                        .duration(200)
                        .attr("r", 50)
```

Now I want to exclude certain nodes and thought to filter would help. Unfortunately it doesn´t. Probably my code is wrong or I need to add those filtering later one. Any idea?

```
 .on("mouseenter", function(d) {
                    d3.select(this)
                        .filter(function() {
                            return !this.graph.nodes.name("usv"))
                        })
                        .transition()
                        .duration(200)
                        .attr("r", 50)
```

Best,

Kristian

Comment: Apply the `.filter` before the `.on` so that the event handler is only attached to the ones of interest.  And I'm not sure `this.graph.nodes.name` bit is functional code.

Comment: Hi @Mark thanks for your fast reply. Unfortunately it doesn´t worked out. If I apply the filter before the "mouseenter" function non of the nodes are displayed. Even if I change the filter in certain ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example implementation:

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <svg width="500" height="500"></svg>
    <script>
      let data = d3.range(10)
        .map(function(d){
          return {
            name: Math.random() > 0.5 ? "usv" : "na",
            x: Math.random() * 480,
            y: Math.random() * 480
          };
        });

      d3.select('svg')
        .selectAll('circle')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('circle')
        .attr('cx', d => d.x)
        .attr('cy', d => d.y)
        .attr('r', 20)
        .attr("fill", d => d.name == "usv" ? "red" : "black")
        .filter((d) => {
          return d.name === "usv";
        })
        .on("mouseenter", function(){
          d3.select(this)
            .transition()
            .duration(200)
            .attr("r", 50);
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @Mark thanks for your code. I will update your answer as it works smooth with D3v6. I missed to mention that I am using D3v4 and as soon as I apply your filter only "usv" is there. I guess may problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: @ICoded, I updated my answer to use d3v4, works just the same.  If you can code up a runnable reproducible example of your issue, I'd be glad to take a look.

Comment: Hi @Mark I found my issue with the help of your adjustment. First a syntax error and secondly I tried to modify to much at once. All fixed all good. Thanks a lot Mark.